# Is .NET dependency injection container implemented by topological sort?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, algorithm, topological-sort

I'm studying Kahn's Algorithm now and figured out that the usage of this alg is solving the topological sort.

I found a document said that the topological sort is always used for dependency, so there's an idea appearing in my mind.

I'm curious about:

1. Is the sort of .NET dependency injection container follow the topological sort?
2. Is it implemented by Kahn's Algorithm?

Comment: The DI container lazily builds factory methods to call the constructor for each service, recursively resolving each dependency. A debug build validates the service definitions by compiling all the constructors.

Comment: Are you specifically interested in asp.net (i.e. .net framework 4.x)?